# Flatten and sort a nested JSON object into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, nested, flatten

I have an object like:

```
{
  '2021': {
    '08': {
      '26': [{'name': 'Bob', age: 34}, {'name': 'Alice', age: 33}],
      '27': [{'name': 'Jane', age: 21}]
    },
    '09': {
      '03': [{'name': 'John', age: 47}, {'name': 'Sue', age: 36}]
    }
  },
  '2022': {
    '04': {
      '05': [{'name': 'David', age: 26}]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to flatten this object into an array of `<year, month, day, name, age>` objects sorted by descending date, so the desired output would be:

```
[
  {'year': '2022', 'month': '04', 'day': '05', 'name': 'David', age: 26},
  {'year': '2021', 'month': '09', 'day': '03', 'name': 'John', age: 47},
  {'year': '2021', 'month': '09', 'day': '03', 'name': 'Sue', age: 36},
  {'year': '2021', 'month': '08', 'day': '27', 'name': 'Jane', age: 21},
  {'year': '2021', 'month': '08', 'day': '26', 'name': 'Bob', age: 34},
  {'year': '2021', 'month': '08', 'day': '26', 'name': 'Alice', age: 33},
]
```

**UPDATE:**

I followed Nina's logic and also split into 2 parts, first flattening into a single-depth array and then sorting. The flattening part I have an "uglier" nested for loop which also works and used the exact same sort code:

```
let output = []
for (const year in data) {
  for (const month in data[year]) {
    for (const day in data[year][month]) {
      for (const person of data[year][month][day]) {
        const merged = Object.assign({
          'year': year,
          'month': month,
          'day': day,
        }, person)
        
        output.push(merged)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not as flexible and I'm not sure how to judge performance differences, but I will be accepting Nina's answer which works.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far?

Comment: That doesn't look too difficult. What problem are you having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split the task into two parts,

1. get a flat array from the data with a recursion,
2. sort by wanted keys descending.

```js
const
    flat = (object, [key, ...keys], values = {}) => Object
        .entries(object)
        .flatMap(([k, v]) => {
            const right = { ...values, [key]: k };
            return Array.isArray(v)
                ? v.map(o => ({ ...right, ...o }))
                : flat(v, keys, right);
        }),
    keys = ['year', 'month', 'day'],
    data = { 2021: { '08': { 26: [{ name: 'Bob', age: 34 }, { name: 'Alice', age: 33 }], 27: [{ name: 'Jane', age: 21 }] }, '09': { '03': [{ name: 'John', age: 47 }, { name: 'Sue', age: 36 }] } }, 2022: { '04': { '05': [{ name: 'David', age: 26 }] } } },
    result = flat(data, keys)
        .sort((a, b) => {
            let r;
            keys.some(k => r = b[k] - a[k]);
            return r;
        });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```